# I keep getting a syntax error, how do i solve this?

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
DECLARE
   c_id c_customer.customer_name%type;
   coin_id1 i_invoice.coin_id%type;
   coin_price c_coin.price%type;
   delivery  i_invoice.delivery_date%type;
   CURSOR i_invoice ,c_coin ,c_customer is
      SELECT customer_name, coin_id, price ,delivery_date
FROM ((invoice
INNER JOIN customer on invoice.customer_id = customer.customer_id)
  INNER JOIN coin on invoice coin_id = coin.coin_id)
WHERE delivery_date BETWEEN '18 MAY 2021' AND  '20 MAY 2021'

BEGIN

   OPEN i_invoice,c_customer,c_coin;
   LOOP

   FETCH c_customers into customer_id ,
         c_coin into coin_id,
         c_coin into price,
         i_invoice into delivery_date;

   EXIT WHEN i_invloice%notfound;

   dbms_output.put_line(customer_id || ' ' || coin_id || ' ' 
                                    || price || ' ' || delivery_date);

   END LOOP;

   CLOSE i_invoice;

END;
/
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting? Though your cursor declaration is not correct.

Comment: One possible source of error: comparing `delivery_date` to **strings**. You must convert those to dates: `to_date('18 MAY 2021', 'dd MON yyyy')`. Very common beginner mistake (but very costly too).

Comment: the error comes at the cursor declaration

Comment: can someone please fix my cursor declaration?

Answer (score 0):

You are using incorrect syntax for the cursor declaration. The correct code should look alike -

```
DECLARE
       c_id c_customer.customer_name%type;
       coin_id1 i_invoice.coin_id%type;
       coin_price c_coin.price%type;
       delivery  i_invoice.delivery_date%type;
       -- CURSOR i_invoice ,c_coin ,c_customer is    --> This is incorrect declaration.
       CURSOR invoice_dtls IS
       SELECT customer_name, coin_id, price ,delivery_date
         FROM ((invoice INNER JOIN customer on invoice.customer_id = customer.customer_id)
               INNER JOIN coin on invoice coin_id = coin.coin_id)
        WHERE delivery_date BETWEEN '2021-05-18' AND  '2021-05-20'
       -- You are missing a semi-colon after this
       ;

BEGIN

   -- OPEN i_invoice,c_customer,c_coin;
   OPEN invoice_dtls;
   LOOP
   
   /*FETCH c_customers into customer_id ,
         c_coin into coin_id,
         c_coin into price,
         i_invoice into delivery_date;*/
   FETCH invoice_dtls
    INTO c_id, coin_id1, coin_price, delivery; 

   EXIT WHEN i_invloice%notfound;

   dbms_output.put_line(c_id || ' ' || coin_id1 || ' ' 
                        || coin_price || ' ' || delivery);

   END LOOP;
   CLOSE i_invoice;

END;
/
```

Comment: keep getting an error here:  OPEN i_invoice,c_customer,c_coin;

Comment: Try my edited code. I have commented out this line.

Comment: the error in your code comes here: SELECT customer_name, coin_id, price ,delivery_date

Comment: Try now. I have updated the date format.

Comment: the error comes here by delivery_date: SELECT customer_name, coin_id, price ,delivery_date

Comment: Please create the demo fiddle with sample data of your tables and share the link here. I will take a look into it.

Comment: @taahirmia -  Even with repeated corrections and adjustments, you _still_ seem to resist posting the _actual error message_.  Software emits error codes and message text for a reason. Please help those from whom you expect assistance, and _post the error messages_.

Comment: the error here is: INTO clause is expected in the select statement

Answer (score 0):

You produced quite a big mess. Let me try to pick some errors:

- in `declare` section, you're using one table names (`i_invoice`, `c_coin`) while cursor's `from` clause suggest different (`invoice`, `coin`)
- cursor should have a name, for example `c1`. Its name can't be `i_invoice ,c_coin ,c_customer`. You'd actually *fetch* cursor into those variables
- `where` clause is *wrong* - if `delivery_date` column's datatype is `date` (I presume it is, as it should be), then don't compare it to strings. `'18 MAY 2021'` is a string. Date literal (I used) is not
- `open` is as wrong as cursor declaration; you'd `open c1`
- `fetch` would fail as well, as there's no `customer_id` in its `select` column list. Also, why are you fetching `c_coin` into both `coin_id` and `price`?

I'd suggest you to use a cursor `for` loop instead. You don't have to explicitly declare any variables, open a cursor, fetch into variables, take care about exiting the loop nor closing the cursor. Something like this (with dummy tables I created, just to show that code compiles):

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd.mm.yyyy';

Session altered.
```

Description:

```
SQL> desc customer
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 CUSTOMER_NAME                                      VARCHAR2(10)
 CUSTOMER_ID                                        NUMBER

SQL> desc invoice
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 COIN_ID                                            NUMBER
 DELIVERY_DATE                                      DATE
 CUSTOMER_ID                                        NUMBER

SQL> desc coin
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 PRICE                                              NUMBER
 COIN_ID                                            NUMBER
```

Contents:

```
SQL> select * from customer;

CUSTOMER_N CUSTOMER_ID
---------- -----------
Littlefoot           1

SQL> select * from invoice;

   COIN_ID DELIVERY_D CUSTOMER_ID
---------- ---------- -----------
         1 19.05.2021           1

SQL> select * from coin;

     PRICE    COIN_ID
---------- ----------
       100          1
```

Code itself:

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> begin
  2    for cur_r in (select t.customer_id,
  3                         t.customer_name,
  4                         c.coin_id,
  5                         c.price,
  6                         i.delivery_date
  7                  from invoice i join customer t on i.customer_id = t.customer_id
  8                                 join coin c     on i.coin_id     = c.coin_id
  9                  where i.delivery_date between date '2021-05-18' and date '2021-05-20'
 10                 )
 11    loop
 12      dbms_output.put_line(cur_r.customer_id
 13                           || ' '
 14                           || cur_r.coin_id
 15                           || ' '
 16                           || cur_r.price
 17                           || ' '
 18                           || cur_r.delivery_date);
 19    end loop;
 20  end;
 21  /
1 1 100 19.05.2021

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

---

If you insist on doing it *your way*, at least declare one cursor variable instead of separate variables.

```
SQL> declare
  2    cursor c1 is
  3      select t.customer_id,
  4                         t.customer_name,
  5                         c.coin_id,
  6                         c.price,
  7                         i.delivery_date
  8                  from invoice i join customer t on i.customer_id = t.customer_id
  9                                 join coin c     on i.coin_id     = c.coin_id
 10                  where i.delivery_date between date '2021-05-18' and date '2021-05-20';
 11    cur_r c1%rowtype;
 12  begin
 13    open c1;
 14    loop
 15      fetch c1 into cur_r;
 16      exit when c1%notfound;
 17
 18      dbms_output.put_line(cur_r.customer_id
 19                           || ' '
 20                           || cur_r.coin_id
 21                           || ' '
 22                           || cur_r.price
 23                           || ' '
 24                           || cur_r.delivery_date);
 25    end loop;
 26  end;
 27  /
1 1 100 19.05.2021

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```